# Why doesn't my atoi implementation work with negative numbers?

Tags: c, atoi

```
#include<stdio.h>

int ft_atoi(char *str)
{
    int i;
    int sign;
    int val;
    int nbr;

    i = 0;
    sign = 1;
    val = 0;
    nbr = 0;
    while(str[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (str[i] == '-')
            sign = -sign;
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;
    while(str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9' && str[i] != '\0')
    {
        nbr = (int) (str[i] - '0');
        val = (val * 10) + nbr;
        i++;
    }
    i++;
    return (val * sign);
}
```

It returns 0 when I try with negative numbers.

Comment: The thing is when you have -ve number it is not going inside while loop. you should check if first character is `-`, you should do `i++` so that it can get next character.

Comment: Apart from being the source of your problem, looping twice is also a huge waste. Oh and you should really pass a `const char *` as such a function is not expected to change the string content. Look how [it simplifies everything with just one loop](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a08491d633f7fb7e)

Comment: Forgot to include the check for digit, of course ist should [look like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5327f86dd3fd7388)

Answer (score 4):

the second while loop breaks if `str[0]` is `'-'`.

```
while(str[i] != '\0')
{
    if (str[i] == '-')
        sign = -sign;
    i++;
}
```

should be

```
if (str[0] == '-')
{
    sign = -1;
    str++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After you have scanned the string for minus signs, you reset `i` to zero, but `str[0]` isn't a valid digit, because it's a minus sign.

You can change the first loop to advance past the first minus sign and the start parsing the numerical value from where the first loop left off:

```
int ft_atoi(char *str)
{
    int i = 0;
    int sign = 1;
    int val = 0;

    while (str[i] == '-') {
        sign = -sign;
        i++;
    }

    while(str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9')
    {
        int nbr = (int) (str[i] - '0');

        val = (val * 10) + nbr;
        i++;
    }

    return (val * sign);
}
```

(There's no need to check that `str[i]` isn't the null character, because if it is a minus sign or a digit, it can't be the null character. The check is useful for testing negatives, however, e.g. when testing that some character isn't a minus.)

Comment: No need to use first `while` loop. you can use `if` instead. bcz there will be only one `-` character.

Comment: @Himanshu: Yes, but I was working fro OP's code. This will parse "--23" as positive 23. The way it was coded in the original post, I'm not sure whether that was intended.

Comment: @M Oehm, nice thought. 2 -ve sign.

Comment: @Himanshu: Well, two minus signs is a bit silly, really. An `if` is enough, but the code shoul probably strip leading white space and recognise a `+` at the beginning, too.

Answer (score 1):

you can just `str++;` in your if when str is negative

```
#include <stdio.h>
int ft_atoi(char *str)
{
    int i;
    int sign;
    int val;
    int nbr;



       i = 0;
        sign = 1;
        val = 0;
        nbr = 0;
        while(str[i] != '\0')
        {
            if (str[i] == '-')
            {

                sign = -sign;
                str++;
            }
            i++;
        }
        i = 0;
        while(str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9' && str[i] != '\0')
        {
            nbr = (int) (str[i] - '0');
            val = (val * 10) + nbr;
            i++;
        }
        i++;
        return (val * sign);
    }
```